# How do you change the _id from ObjectID to Number in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use mongoose js program to do the inserts, however I want to use 1,2,3,4 etc as the ids NOT to use the BSON ObjectID automatically created for me.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var dbHost = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mong_db';

//var newID = mongoose.model('bookSchema', { _id: Number, name: String });

 mongoose.connect(dbHost);

 //Create a schema for Book

  var bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  _ id: Number, 

  name: String,

  //Also creating index on field isbn

  isbn: {type: String, index: true},

  author: String,

   pages: Number

  });

>Updated 


var book1 = new Book({

 _id = 1
name:"Mongoose Demo 1",

isbn: "MNG123",

author: "Author1,  Author2",

pages: 123

});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose auto increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357965/mongoose-auto-increment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the type used in your schema when you call the model constructor.

```
var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { _id: Number, name: String });
```

Then pass in an `_id` field when you store the object.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test-mongo-id');

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { _id: Number, name: String });

var kitty = new Cat({ _id: 1, name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save(function (err) {
  console.log(err || 'meow');
  Cat.findOne({_id: 1}, function (err, cat) {
    console.log(err || 'Cat:', cat)
  });
});
```

Output:

```
meow
Cat: { _id: 1, name: 'Zildjian', __v: 0 }
```

You're schema should have `_id: Number` in it like this:

```
var bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: Number,    // <-- You're missing this
  name: String,    
  //Also creating index on field isbn    
  isbn: {type: String, index: true},    
  author: String,    
  pages: Number    
});
```

Comment: can you check my updated question if I did it right?

Comment: what does the schema for `Book` look like? e.g. `mongoose.model('Book', {..?..});`

Comment: its correct except that its the schema for `newID` instead of `Book`

Comment: and the `bookSchema` in the second part of your update is missing `_id: Number`

Comment: I got an error: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ValidationError: Book validation failed

Comment: Book.update({_id: Number, isbn : {$eq: 'MNG125'}}, {$set: {name: "Mongoose Demo 3.1"}}, function(err, result){  LIKE THIS

Comment: with your latest update, you are still missing `_id: Number,` from the bookSchema - i've updated my answer

Comment: when you call update, pass the number you want, not the type `Number` - `Book.update( { _id: 1, ...})`

Comment: should do it  like that in my book part: _id = 1,

Comment: its difficult to know what you're asking when you keep changing the question around - please show the full code with details of exactly what is not working and any error messages you're getting - although if you just try what i've put in my answer, it will work. I just tried it - it works :)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: You're welcome - you might want to give this a read before your next question ;) - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To also answer the `I want to use 1,2,3,4 etc` part of the question, you'd need to [generate auto-incrementing IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685250/auto-increment-ids-in-mongoose/32686685#32686685), which requires a round-trip to the database. There's a reason MongoDB generates those unique IDs.